# C# Using PrintWindow

Tags: c#, windows-7, screen-capture, window-handles

I am trying to capture a window in win7 without disabling aero and I hear [PrintWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162869%28VS.85%29.aspx) Works.

But I'm not sure how to use it, I found some [articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997649.aspx) but I can't see any image or bitmap output in any of them

Has anyone ever had experience with this function and knows how to use it?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.printwindow

Comment: Thank you @Adrian, @David fails - I am ASKING for an example code, I have no code -_-"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Previous link [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.printwindow).

Code sample from the same link:

```
Graphics g = form.CreateGraphics();
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(form.Size.Width, form.Size.Height, g);
Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
IntPtr dc = memoryGraphics.GetHdc();
bool success = PrintWindow(form.Handle, dc, 0);
memoryGraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc);
// bmp now contains the screenshot
```

Also as specified in the above link you can use managed [Control.DrawToBitamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx) to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Always got black screens. Your answer made me realize, that I had a wrong order. First I saved bmp, afterwards I released DC, although it must be vice versa.